# Eror RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I had an error when I wanted to deploy NLTK on heroku, I have created a nltk.txt file and created nltk dependencies in the requirements.txt, but I experienced an error

[Image For Log Eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2TA3.jpg)

/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/runpy.py:127: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))

I've tried several solutions but still can't solve the problem. Thank you in advance.